# Why do I get an error message using "sudo apt-get update"?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I get this error message while trying to update from the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ffmulticonverter/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ffmulticonverter/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It is referring to a specific app, but the whole update is rendered useless (I guess due to this error).

Any ideas what's going on and why I can't update my OS? The graphical update won't work either.

Comment: Disabling the repo in `system settings --> software & updates --> other software` should resolve it, till _xenial_ supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PPA doesn't have a release for Xenial, the latest version this repository supports is Utopic.

This article may help:
http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2015/12/install-ff-multi-converter-172-on.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. What's the best way to uninstall the current version? I am not very good at the commands. It's sudo purge something, right?

Comment: Yeah, ppa-purge:

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ffmulticonverter` - you'll then need to run `sudo apt-get update` to update your software repositories after the purge.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the reason that the PPA does not have a Xenial release, as seen in screenshot below. [PPA Link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ffmulticonverter/stable/ubuntu/dists/)

[image: xenial release not present]

If you need to get rid of this error, remove the PPA from software sources and then do a repo update.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does this mean I am stuck at ffmulticonverter Xenial? I can never get it updated?